# corrupted and unreadable php_imagick.dll

Tags: php, dll, imagick

I have an error in my xampp or php with `php_imagick.dll`. Recently my pc suffered from file corruption and had to reinstall apps and others and it is fixed now. So I re-installed xampp and installed it in another location.

Now I am getting this kind of error:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
> 'php_imagick.dll' (tried: F:\xampp\php\ext\php_imagick.dll  (The file
> or directory is corrupted and unreadable),
> F:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_imagick.dll.dll (The specified module could
> not be found)) in Unknown on line 0

Imagick is already installed so i just need to replace the extension files. my xampp is installed in `F:` php_imagick.dll is located at `F:\xampp\php\ext`. The php_imagick.dll I have now is also new so I do not know why it can be corrupted and unreadable.

Comment: Are you positively sure that your hard disk drive is not damaged? You don't normally get corrupted files unless the drive is about to die, expect maybe if your computer crashed catastrophically write _writing_ files.

Comment: Why the `php_php_imagick.dll.dll` file has double extension? Could you provide the minimal reproducible code so others can help in the problem?

Comment: @PéterSzilvási I'd say that, for backward compatibility, PHP tries both the new and the old syntax if it cannot find the corresponding DLL: `extension = php_foo.dll` first looks for `php_foo.dll` and then `php_php_foo.dll.dll`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming issue. Reinstall PHP.